# Prometheus remote_read returns 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: prometheus

I have created a REST-API that returns a String.

REST Code:

```
@RestController
public class CSwScaler {

    @GetMapping(path = "/scaler", produces = "text/plain")
    public String scaler(){

        /* Logic */
    }
}

# HELP session_count_now This gives session count
# TYPE session_count_now gauge
session_count_now 4.0
```

I want Prometheus to read this at certain interval and keep it as a metrics for further work.
In Prometheus.yml file, I have added:

```
remote_read:
  - url: http://loclahost:8080/scaler
    read_recent: true
    name: scaler01
```

When I go to check that metrics, I get 405

[image]

Any idea what all I am missing or did wrong?

Running the REST request directly returns results.

Replacing localhost from URL to HOST_NAME also does not help in case of prometheus. Whereas both works in case of curl or direct browser.

Thanks,
Swaraj

Comment: Which HTTP method is your rest-api listening? From the 405 error, maybe you are exposing it under one that prometheus does not like. Try using `GET` if you are not already using it.

Comment: It is GET. Edited the question with REST code

Comment: It is sending data to Prometheus.